unpivot multiple columns in Oracle
I have such table with 5 columns
order code1 value1 code2 value2
I want to to have one column for code and one column for value.
I can use union all
select order,code1,value1 from table
union all
select order,code2,vakue2 from table
How can I fo it with unpivot clause?

You can use:
SELECT "order", code, value
FROM   table_name
       UNPIVOT (
         (code, value) FOR type IN (
           (code1, value1) AS 1,
           (code2, value2) AS 2
         )
       )

Which, for the sample data:
CREATE TABLE table_name ("order", code1, value1, code2, value2) AS
SELECT 1, 2, 3, 4,  5 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 FROM DUAL;

Outputs:



order
CODE
VALUE




1
2
3


1
4
5


6
7
8


6
9
10



fiddle

select orderid, code, value from data 
unpivot (
    value FOR code IN (
                value1, value2
            )
)
;

(order being a reserved word changed to orderid)

This doesn't output the expected result fiddle
